# Connecting Heroku app to private GitHub repository for deploying on Heroku

Tags: heroku, github

I have an organization's private GitHub repository that I am trying to connect a Heroku app to, using the Heroku Dashboard from a browser. In the settings of my GitHub account (that is linked to Heroku), under **OAuth Applications**, I can see **Heroku Dashboard**, and under **Permissions**, it says *Full control of private repositories*.

However, when I navigate to the Heroku app page and select this GitHub repo from the select-list and click **Connect**, I get the message:

```
Item could not be modified:
Admin access to repository required
```

On GitHub, my account has *Write* access for the repo. Moreover, as mentioned above, Heroku Dashboard has *Full control of private repositories*. Can anybody help me figure out what access needs to be granted where? I would really appreciate that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never mind. That private GitHub repo had been created by someone else who had since left the company. I had *Write* access but that is not enough. When I created a new GitHub repo and an app on Heroku myself, I could connect them without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem when someone without admin access to the github repo requested the github access in Heroku.  He had to revoke his access in github before we could log back into Heroku with an account that had admin access in github and properly connect the accounts.